# Create a Dropdown Menu on Tkinter with Data from excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, xlrd

I'd like to Create a Dropdown Menu on Tkinter via using Tkinter and xlrd. 
The Values of the dropdown Menu shall be from an excel-list. So far I only have this:

```
i = 0
while i < 96:
    i = i+1
    m=sheet.cell_value(i,1)
    print(m)
mbuttonMaterial = Menubutton(tkFenster, text='Material')     
picks   = Menu(mbuttonMaterial)               
mbuttonMaterial.config(menu=picks)
picks.add_command(label=sheet.cell_value(8,1)+ '/'+sheet.cell_value(8,2),command = ChooseMaterial)
mbuttonMaterial.pack()
mbuttonMaterial.config(bg='white', bd=4, relief=RAISED)
mbuttonMaterial.place(x=54,y=200, width=100, height = 50)
```

I would like to use m as a variable instead of the value 8. But only integers are allowed. Do I have to use openpyxl? Do you have any suggestions? Maybe there's another way. This is the first time I'm using Python.

Comment: You should simplify your question so that it refers to a particular task or piece of code.

Comment: I have different names of Materials, listed in excel. These names shall be shown in a dropdown Menu.

Comment: And your point is? You should probably split your code into two blocks: one that gets the materials and another that uses these materials in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to retrieve the items from your excel document, you can try adding them to a dictionary along their varType. Here is a modified example from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menubutton.htm):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menubutton, Menu, IntVar, RAISED

top = Tk()

mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="condiments", relief=RAISED )
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

menuItemVars = { "mayoVar": "mayo", "ketchVar": "ketchup", "mustardVar": "mustard" }

for key, value in menuItemVars.items():
    print(key, value)
    key = IntVar()
    mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=value, variable=key)


mb.pack()
top.mainloop()
```